# The Difference between Dann and Sodann

Tags: meaning

I am under the impression that "dann" and "sodann" both mean "then." Is there any type of difference in their meaning or usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*dann* is more versatile, You cannot replace it with *sodann* everywhere.
E.g.

*dann* is also *then* in the sense of *if .., **then** .. else..* (*wenn, dann*)

Also in questions

> wenn nicht hier, wo dann? - *If not here, where else?*

temporal point in the future

> wenn es dann immer noch regnet  - *If it is still raining at that point*

*sodann* can always be replaced by *dann*, however.

*sodann/dann* means:

1) temporal ordering (*then, followed by*)

> Ich tat dies und *dann* jenes. - *I did this and **then** that.*
>   Ich tat zuerst dies, *sodann* jenes.

2) further/furthermore/also

> zur Grundausstattung gehört *sodann* ein Klappmesser - *The basic kit **also** contains a knife*

In general, you will not hear *sodann* very often. I know it more from older texts rather than spoken language.

Comment: When can "sodann" be used?

Comment: @user109871 : updated the answer to include usage and meaning of sodann